# Two Connections at once

Tags: windows, connection, wifi, system, lan

So basically I have a WiFi network which has internet, then I have a LAN network that does not have internet its just a dummy internet so I can test things with higher speeds. But here's my issue since the LAN doesn't have internet when I plug it in my computer doesn't keep internet even though I am still connected to my WiFi which has internet. any solutions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

sorry guys. I just figured out that both the gateways on my routers were the same and that was causing the issue.